# HTML / CSS trying to move input text box to a set positon

Tags: html, css, search-engine

Hey if anyone is able to assist it would be much appreciated, I have no idea how to move the following textbox to where I want it to be.
[image: Text Input]

This is my HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css">


</head>

<body>

<img src="../Resources/MainBrowser.png" alt="SearchEngineGIF" class="custom2">
<img src="../Resources/SearchEngineGIF.gif" alt="SearchEngineGIF" class="custom1">

<input type="text" placeholder="Insert Keyword Here">


</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS behind it:

```
.custom1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: translateY(-210px);
  width: 23%;
}

.custom2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: translateY(+25px);
  width: 25%;
}

input[type=text]{
    width:20%;
    border:2px solid #000000 ;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin:8px 0;
    outline:none;
    padding:8px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    transition:.3s;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }

input[type=text]:focus{
    border-color:dodgerBlue;
    box-shadow:0 0 8px 0 dodgerBlue;

  }

input[type=text]::placeholder{
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

It would also be useful if anyone knew how to make it not move when zooming in and out, Setting the position to fixed doesnt help as I am moving a gif inside of the Image by transforming it up/ down y pixels

EDIT - MainBrowser.png is the whole image above "Insert Keyword Here" textbox, minus "Geoorgle" which is SearchEngineGIF.gif

Comment: what is the output you want?  is that image shown above? what is mainBrowser image in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead you can just use the form tag

```
<form style="width:25%;height:auto;">
<img src="yourimage.jpg" style="width:25%;">
<br>
<input type="text" style="width:20%;"><img src="searchimage.jpg" style="width:5%;">
</form>
```

Change the source of the images and the width according to your need.

You can also use the table tag if you want

And about the image not moving, once you fix the position, put the top and left parameters for the form in the style.

Example:

```
top:25%;
left:25%;
```

Comment: Ive done it, but now the images are sort of side by side. Im also not sure how to implement top:25%; etc. because It isnt moving the images up and down

Comment: Ohh i see what you mean by setting its position to fixed

Comment: @OrangePear style="position:fixed;"

Comment: Ah thankyou very much, I had that but only in the CSS. Now its in the HTML it is working :)

Comment: Most Welcome ;)